# como puedo retornar un array la cual no se el nombre de la array.¿con Object?

Tags: javascript

Cordial saludo. Me encuentro confundido, tengo que solucionar este problema pero no me dice el nombre del array por una lado y encontré que puede ser un objeto global y por ende usara `Object` pero nose si hay que usar `this`.

Por otro lado tengo que usar ciclos for para iterar tanto en el argumento, como en el el array que posee objetos, que a su ves poseen las propiedades.

Pido una colaboración para saber en donde está mi error o si hice todo mal. Abrazo.

```
function sumarElTipo(vehiculos) {
  // La funcion llamada 'sumarElTipo' recibe un array de strings como argumento
  // que contiene tipos de vehiculos y debe devolver un objeto con la cantidad
  // de veces que se repita cada tipo.
  // El objeto que devuelve tiene como propiedades el nombre de cada vehiculo y su valor es la cantidad de veces que se repite.
  // Ej:
  // sumarElTipo(['auto', 'moto', 'auto']); debe retornar {auto: 2, moto: 1}
  // Tip: podes usar el ciclo for o el metodo de Array 'reduce'

  // Tu código aca:




  var vehiculosPropiedades = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < vehiculos.length; i++) {
    vehiculosPropiedades.push(vehiculos[i]);
   }

  
  var propiedadValor = [];
  for (var j = 0; j < Object.length; j++) {
      if (vehiculosPropiedades === Object[j].nombre ) {
           propiedadValor.push( Object[j].valor) 
                    
      }
    }
  
    return propiedadValor;

}
```

Comment: Si sabes el nombre del array, vehiculos. A tí te da igual cómo se llame el array FUERA de la función, dentro de ella el array se llama igual que el parámetro que tienes declarado, vehiculos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tratando de respetar tu código lo corregí, para que funcione.

Lo que corregí fue lo siguiente

En tu primer ciclo recorres tu objeto de vehículos e insertas a un nuevo array, pero no validas que no exista por lo que te dejara una copia de el mismo array de vehículos.

```
 var vehiculosPropiedades = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < vehiculos.length; i++) {
    vehiculosPropiedades.push(vehiculos[i]);
   }
```

```
var vehiculosPropiedades = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < vehiculos.length; i++) {
    if(!vehiculosPropiedades[vehiculos[i]]){
      vehiculosPropiedades.push(vehiculos[i]); //Si no existe lo inserta
     }
  }
```

En tu segundo ciclo es donde intentas meter la cantidad de vehiculos que hay de el mismo tipo, pero generas un array y metes un valor que no se ha calculado.

```
 var propiedadValor = [];
  for (var j = 0; j < Object.length; j++) {
      if (vehiculosPropiedades === Object[j].nombre ) {
           propiedadValor.push( Object[j].valor) 
                    
      }
    }
```

```
var propiedadValor = {};
  for (var j = 0; j < vehiculosPropiedades.length; j++) {
    var cantidad = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < vehiculos.length; i++) {
      if(vehiculos[i] === vehiculosPropiedades[j]){
        cantidad++;
      }
    }
    propiedadValor[vehiculosPropiedades[j]] = cantidad;
```

```js
function sumarElTipo(vehiculos) {
  // La funcion llamada 'sumarElTipo' recibe un array de strings como argumento
  // que contiene tipos de vehiculos y debe devolver un objeto con la cantidad
  // de veces que se repita cada tipo.
  // El objeto que devuelve tiene como propiedades el nombre de cada vehiculo y su valor es la cantidad de veces que se repite.
  // Ej:
  // sumarElTipo(['auto', 'moto', 'auto']); debe retornar {auto: 2, moto: 1}
  // Tip: podes usar el ciclo for o el metodo de Array 'reduce'

  // Tu código aca:
  var vehiculosPropiedades = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < vehiculos.length; i++) {
    //Valid< que no exista el vehiculo en el arreglo para dejar unicos
    if(!vehiculosPropiedades[vehiculos[i]]){
      vehiculosPropiedades.push(vehiculos[i]); //Si no existe lo inserta
     }
  }
  var propiedadValor = {};
  //Recorre los vehiculos distintos
  for (var j = 0; j < vehiculosPropiedades.length; j++) {
    var cantidad = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < vehiculos.length; i++) {
      //Vuelve a recorrer el array principal para sacar la cantidad de vehuculos que hay
      if(vehiculos[i] === vehiculosPropiedades[j]){
        cantidad++;
      }
    }
    //No regresara un array, sera un objeto, por lo que le generamos una propiedad y la cantidad de Items
    propiedadValor[vehiculosPropiedades[j]] = cantidad;
  }
  return propiedadValor;
}
var suma = sumarElTipo(['auto', 'moto', 'auto']);
console.log(suma);
```

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres hacerlo usando reduce (opción que te dan en el enunciado), podrías hacer algo así:

```js
arr = ["auto", "moto", "auto"];

function sumarElTipo(vehiculos){
    return vehiculos.reduce(function (acc, curr){/*Usando la función reduce, vamos a tener acc
        que es la variable donde vamos a guardar nuestros valores y curr, que es la variable donde en 
        cada iteración del "loop" tendremos el valor actual, es decir, primero valdrá auto, luego moto, luego auto...*/
        if(acc[curr] == undefined){//Si act no tiene una clave como la actual, la creamos con valor 1
            acc[curr] = 1;
        }else{//Si ya tiene la clave, simplmente incrementamos su valor en 1
            acc[curr] ++;
        }
        return acc;//Al terminar la iteración devolvemos el valor acc
    },
    {}/*Pasamos un segundo parámetro al reduce, que será nuestro valor inicial. Esto significa que queremos que
    acc no tenga valor en la primera iteración. De lo contrario el valor de acc en la primera iteración sería el 
    valor del primer elemento del array, en este caso "auto"*/
    );
}
console.log(sumarElTipo(arr));
```

Puedes comprobarlo, el valor será "auto": 2, "moto": 1.

Si tienes cualquier duda no dudes en preguntar!